# ActionBarDrawerToggle without custom toolbar

Tags: java, android

I want to use ActionBarDrawerToggle without having custom toolbar instead using current actionBar

my code goes as follow :

```
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.grid);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, actionbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
```

I know I should use :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and use toolBar instead of action bar in ActionBarDrawerToggle but can I use ActionBarDrawerToggle without having new toolbar.

Error I get :

```
error: incompatible types: ActionBar cannot be converted to Toolbar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that by removing actionBar my code now goes like this :

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.grid, R.drawable.contact) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
```